# How to update album art of any specific song

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am creating an app from which I could update album art of the songs, I have tried mp3agic library but it's not working for me. I have already read similar questions related to this but I don't have album id of the song only I have is the location and filename, Is there any way to find album id of the song by it's name or update manually with any library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String DISPLAY_NAME = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String projection[] = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
    String selection = DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"your file name.mp3"};
    String order = null;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, order);
    // **now use cursor** //
```

Comment: Yes, it does. now cursor has an album id.

Comment: Thanks a lot man finally found the solution i was struggling to this since morning, i really appreciate your help 
I have one doubt you used MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME what exactly it contains i used MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI but it failed

Comment: You're Welcome.